# Using a nested foreach to group data

Tags: c#

I have a sample List below. In my main, I want to be able to loop through the queryResult and based on TotalNumberOfUsersInGrp value,
print the names of the first 5 users in first group then next 5 in another group.

I am unable to proceed as you can only use foreach with a collection.

How can I proceed please?

```
        public class PlayerInformation
            {
                public string fullName { get; set; }
                public string rating { get; set; }     
            }

            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Int32  TotalNumberOfUsersInGrp = 5;     
                    List<PlayerInformation> objGetPlayerInfor =  RankPlayers();
                    var queryResult = objGetPlayerInfor.OrderByDescending(q => q.rating);     

                    foreach (var item in queryResult)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in TotalNumberOfUsersInGrp)
                        {
                            //Todo...
                            //Print Group 1 as a header 
                            //Print the fullName of the first 5 players under the title group1
                            //Next Print Group 2 as a header
                            //Print the 5 next names under the group 2 header.
                        }
                    }
                }

                public static List<PlayerInformation> RankPlayers()
                {          
                    List<PlayerInformation> objPlayers = new List<PlayerInformation>();
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Tola", rating = "1001"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "David", rating = "1002"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Bayo", rating = "1003"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Sumbo", rating = "1005"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Demola", rating = "1008"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Patrick", rating = "2001"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Folusho", rating = "2004"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Olawale", rating = "2006"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Johnson", rating = "2008"});
                    objPlayers.Add( new PlayerInformation{fullName = "Ibrahim", rating = "1006"});
                    return objPlayers.ToList();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use nested foreach? The first foreach puts all the player's results (by rate descending). If you want to print 5 player's at once, you can use another for loop out side or just print 5 players in the first foreach loop like this:

```
    int playerIndex=0;
    int groupIndex=1;
    foreach (var item in queryResult)
    {
         if((playerIndex%TotalNumberOfUsersInGrp)==0){
               Console.WriteLine("group:" + groupIndex);
               groupIndex++;
         }
         Console.WriteLine("player:" + item.fullName);
         playerIndex++;
    }
```

Comment: And to answer your question, I don't have to use a nested loop. Anything that works is fine.

Comment: It works for me.. I mistyped in the code. To print the player full name, you should use item.fullName, not item[i]

Comment: I've done this on ConsoleApplication. This is the only part I changed: 
int playerIndex = 0;
            int groupIndex = 1;
            foreach (var item in queryResult)
            {
                if ((playerIndex % TotalNumberOfUsersInGrp) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("header:" + groupIndex);
                    groupIndex++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("player:" + item.fullName);
                playerIndex++;
            }

Comment: Thanks It works very well. Can you please explain this statement   if ((playerIndex % TotalNumberOfUsersInGrp) == 0)

Comment: the foreach loop will go 10 times, and puts it's elements into item every time. The playerIndex stands for the number of loop. when playerIndex is 0, it means the first loop where there has been nothing printed yet. So you print group header1 there. When playerIndex is 5, it means that it's in the 6th loop which means that the top 5 players are printed. So you print group header2 there. After header2, the next top 5 players will be printed